# Socket IO not work with LocationListener in Android

Tags: java, android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I do not understand the issue
This . when I was still running but socket.emit code app is not running . I try to run it , but it still vs asyn or BroadcastReceiver inactive.

Can I fix this and how to fix ? :

**Client.java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button bnt;
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;
Location location = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
public boolean msend = false;
public Socket mSocket;

{
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket("http://khanhip.ddns.net:4001");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mSocket.connect();
    mSocket.emit("id",14235);
    mSocket.emit("upload","Hello upload");
    bnt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    new ui().execute();
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, location.getLatitude() + "",             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            location.set(location);
            msend =true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle   extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    Emitter.Listener listener = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,args[0].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        }
    };
    // mSocket.on("log",listener);
    config();

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case 10 : config();
            break;
    }
}
public void config(){
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET}
                            , 10);
                }
                return;
            }
    if (locationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }
class  ui extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while (true) {
            while (msend) {
                publishProgress();
                return null;
            }
            System.out.println("in");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        System.out.println("out");
        mSocket.emit("update","HI MOTHER"); // code not work
    }
}
}
```

**Server.js**

```
  var express = require("express");
  var app = express();
  var server = require("http").createServer(app);
  var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
  server.listen(4000);
  var listsocket = [];
  var list =[];
  var clientid;
  var Location = {};
  io.sockets.on("connection",function(socket){
    socket.on("upload",function (data) {
     console.log(data);

   });
     socket.on("id",function (data) {
     console.log(data);

     });
  });``
```

Comment: `sockets`, on a programming level, are not `socket.io` related... is your question about sockets or about the protocol implemented by socket.io?

Comment: no code faile mSocket.on("log",listener); when i code out onCreat... can you help me ??

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not a Java person. Perhaps if you update the question, replace the `sockets` tag with `socket.io`, someone who knows the answer will see the question.